# Cauchy Sequences bounded away from zero.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

[image]

[image]

[image]

> Is there a positive real number which can be written as a Cauchy sequence, such that this Cauchy sequence is bounded away from zero and also this sequence contains infinite number of positive and negative rationals.

e.g. zero can be written as a Cauchy sequence of,

$0.1, \ -0.01, \ 0.001, \ -0.0001, .... $

which has infinite number of negative and positive rationals.

Is this possible for a positive real number ?

I think it is not possible since the difference of two term, $|a_m - a_n|$, in a sequence will never tend to zero since the limit is a positive number ?

Is there a proof which does not use terms 'positive number' and 'limit' ?

Comment: I think you answered your own question :)  If we suppose the limit is $L > 0$, then we can never find $N$ such that $m,n \geq N \Rightarrow |a_m - a_n| < L$.

Comment: Is there a proof which does not use terms 'positive number' and 'limit' ? I am trying to prove this just using properties of cauchy sequences and absolute values ?

Comment: I don't have a concrete real number $L$ yet.

Comment: Note that the definition of positive real number you are given involves the notion of a limit, so anything you prove is likely to have to refer to the notion of a limit somewhere.